# Load a saved image from documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocument

I have used the code given [here](http://www.wmdeveloper.com/2010/09/save-and-load-uiimage-in-documents.html) to save and load images

It works fine when i use it together in one view controller, but when i use the saveImage method in one view controller and try to load the image in another view controller the image returned  blank...

In view controller A i use the following to save a image

```
- (void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image
{
    NSLog(@"saveimage called");

    if (image != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Image not null");
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          @"test.png" ];
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        QrImageView.image = nil;
    }
}
```

And in view controller say B I'm loading the image using..

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage
{
    NSError *error;

    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      @"test.png" ];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    // Write out the contents of home directory to console
    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);

    return image;
}
```

I also get the content of the file in console but i dont understand why the image is blank

```
2013-07-06 14:13:19.750 YouBank[500:c07] Documents directory: (
    "test.png"
)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong...

```
EDIT:
```

In the view controller B on the viewDidload method i do the following

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    ImageView.image=[self loadImage];
    ImageName.text = @"Cash Withdrawal";
}
```

Comment: Is the UIImage instance nil after imageWithContentsOfFile?

Comment: It seems as though the problem is with displaying the UIImage after it is loaded rather than the loading of the data itself. Can you show the code you're using in order to show it onscreen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're updating your UIImageView with the UIImage only upon viewDidLoad. You need to add an update once you are done obtaining it from the filesystem (preferably on a background thread). So it would look something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^{
    UIImage *loadedImage = [self loadImage];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
         ImageView.image = loadedImage;
    });
});
```

I would also recommend to use names starting with lowercase characters for instance names, so you should rename ImageView -> imageView

Comment: So let me understand the situation - you're getting a UIImage from loadImage (not nil), assigning it to the ImageView (is this an IBOutlet? Is it hooked up right?) and still not seeing the image?

Comment: yes... i even added this ImageName.text = @"dnsdjkvn" in the mainqueue  and the text got updated..but the image is still blank

Comment: Try running this on the iOS simulator. Navigate to the PNG resource in Finder and look at it. Is it blank as well?

Comment: How is the UIImageView set up? Any resize mask? autolayout active on the storyboard? Try setting the background color and see if it's visible once the controller's view is visible. Load the image with a delay to see what happens once it's loaded

Comment: Oh... LOL i was displaying a black image on black background....but the next thing i want to load the next image on a button click. A gallery kind of thing where you can navigate through images......any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    //Document Directory
    #define kAppDirectoryPath   NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)


    #pragma mark - File Functions - Document/Cache Directory Functions
    -(void)createDocumentDirectory:(NSString*)pStrDirectoryName
    {
        NSString *dataPath = [self getDocumentDirectoryPath:pStrDirectoryName];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:NULL];
    }

    -(NSString*)getDocumentDirectoryPath:(NSString*)pStrPathName
    {
        NSString *strPath = @"";
        if(pStrPathName)
            strPath = [[kAppDirectoryPath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pStrPathName];

        return strPath;
    }
```

When your write photo

```
        [self createDocumentDirectory:@"MyPhotos"];
        NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory()  stringByAppendingPathComponent:strImageName];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgBg.image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

When you get the file
**Edit**

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[FunctionManager getDocumentDirectoryPath:@"MyPhotos"] error:&error];
    if (!error) {
           NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.png'"];
       NSArray *imagesOnly = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
            for (int i=0;i<[imagesOnly count]; i++) {
                [arrSaveImage addObject:[imagesOnly objectAtIndex:i]]; //arrSaveImage is Array of image that fetch one by one image and stored in the array
            }
 }


    NSString *strPath=[self getDocumentDirectoryPath:@"MyPhotos"]; // "MyPhotos" is Your Directory name
    strPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",strPath,[arrSaveImage objectAtIndex:i]]; //You can set your image name instead of [arrSaveImage objectAtIndex:i]
    imgBackScroll.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strPath]];
```

it may help you.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the arrSaveImage??

Comment: it is just image name, my requirement is more then one image so i used above code and put it in for loop to fetch one by one image

Comment: Still the same :'(... I also added this piece of code     NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:strPath error:&error]);
But it is giving null... I replaced strImageName and [arrSaveImage objectAtIndex:i] by @"abcd.png"

Comment: are you using Any folder in DocumentDirectory?

Comment: No... i am also getting the image if i use my code in the same view controller(mentioned it in my question)... but when i again do it from the start of application and try to load the image elsewhere in a new view controller the image is blank..